# Implementing a NoSQL backend

Tags: python, django, nosql

We have our own custom NoSQL storage system (sort of a document database), and we want a Django app above it.

I want to write a backend that will allow me to connect to our database. I don't care about the Django ORM because we have our own library for querying our database.

1. What would be the simplest & quickest way of doing this?   Rewriting
   & overriding the `django.db.backends.base` classes seems too much of
   a hassle since we don't care about Django's ORM. What we basically
   need is a way to keep a connection alive, and have the queries run
   against the database from our `views.py` file
2. If we want to keep the Django auth system, should we rewrite that part so that  Django creates the User model etc. in our DB? Perhaps we should have two databases, a simple RDBMS for the authentication part, and the rest of the data in our custom database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try reading the source of [django-nonrel](https://github.com/django-nonrel), Django non-rel is a project to support Django on non-relational ('NoSQL') databases. And should give you a good insight and make your own judgement what will be the best approach for your use case.

Comment: And how about the second question? If I decide to write something on my own, should I also make it compatible with the Django Auth system, or rather use two databases? Is that even logical, or plain stupid to do something like that?

Comment: both your approach using one NoSQL, and combine NoSQL and RDBMs are possible, just look at django-norel, [django-monogonaut](https://github.com/pydanny/django-mongonaut) for some insights

Comment: Yeah I already wrote something pretty basic that keeps a connection alive for our DB, it's just that I can't figure out if it's worth the time writing an adapter for the auth system, or using the combination of NoSQL & RDBMS :) That's basically my question

Comment: lol ok. In that case I will say use one of the django forks and you can keep everything in one NoSQL. It's more maintainable in my perspective :)